# How to configure default DispatcherServlet?

Tags: spring-boot

`throwExceptionIfNoHandlerFound` was introduced in `DispatcherServlet` in Spring 4.0.

I have tried to figure out how to set this property in the autoconfigured `DispatcherServlet` provided by Spring Boot, but no luck.

Some digging suggests the snippet below should work, but it doesn't.

```
@Bean
public ServletContextInitializer servletContextInitializer() {
    return new ServletContextInitializer() {
        @Override
        public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
            servletContext.setInitParameter("throwExceptionIfNoHandlerFound", "true");

        }
    };
}
```

Comment: That wouldn't work unless the `DispatcherServlet` took it's configuration from the servlet context (generally) as opposed to the servlet's own configuration (specifically).

Answer (score 5):

With a `BeanPostProcessor` you can modify a bean after its construction/init phase. You could write a `BeanPostProcessor` which only modifyes the `DispatcherServlet`.

```
public class DispatcherServletConfigurer implements BeanPostProcessor {

    public Object postProcessBeforeInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {
         if (bean instanceof DispatcherServlet) {
             ((DispatcherServlet) bean).setThrowExceptionIfNoHandlerFound(true);
         }
         return bean;
    }

    public Object postProcessAfterInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {
        return bean;
    }
}
```

Then simply add this as a `@Bean` to your configuration.

Comment: Thank you very much M. Deinum

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a `@Bean` of type `DispatcherServlet` and setting whatever properties you need directly.

Comment: Yes, that works. Maybe something to consider to expose as an application property in Spring Boot.  Note to others struggling with this: for the setting explained above to have any effect, you would have to turn of some auto config in Spring Boot: `@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {WebMvcAutoConfiguration.class, ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration.class})`

Comment: Wouldn't it also work with a `BeanPostProcessor` in the case of Spring Boot.

Comment: Probably a `BeanPostProcessor` would work. (And I'm not sure what the excludes would achieve.)